# Will a factory reset launch to the android stock launcher or can I use my own?

Tags: root-access, file-system, default-applications

I was silly enough to uninstall my android 4.2.1 stock launcher and instead, installed nova launcher. I works 100% but this one annoying message keeps popping up every 5 seconds saying that the process com.google.process.gapps has stopped, so I looked at why, came to the conclusion that a factory reset would solve that. now I was wondering whether a factory reset would boot to nova launcher? I have a feeling that it will but I wasn't sure so I am just asking.

thank you for all answers.

Answer (score 0):

Factory reset will wipe all user apps, thus if you installed Nova regularly (not as a system app), then it will be gone, and after the reset you will be greeted by the default launcher. If there isn't one *and* USB debugging is not enabled (very likely), you're stuck.

At this moment you should definitely install a launcher (Nova or whatever) as a system app to prevent the worst case.